# Overlapped images on small size browser Isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm having some trouble with a isotope js. The website so you can see the real example is [this one](http://www.mi5studio.com/#projects)

I will try to resume the script and how I'm loading, maybe someone will notice what am I doing wrong. But the main problem is that when I load the page and the browser is in a size less then 900 px width, the images are overlapped and I dont know why.

```js
            // init Isotope
            var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
              itemSelector: '.grid-item',
              percentPosition: true,
              masonry: {
                columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
              }
            });
            // layout Isotope after each image loads
            $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
              $grid.isotope('layout');
            });  

            // store filter for each group
            var filters = {};

            $('#filters').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
              var $this = $(this);
              // get group key
              var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
              var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
              // set filter for group
              filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
              // combine filters
              var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
              // set filter for Isotope
              $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
            });

            // change is-checked class on buttons
            $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
              var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
              $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
                $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
                $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
              });
            });

            // flatten object by concatting values
            function concatValues( obj ) {
              var value = '';
              for ( var prop in obj ) {
                value += obj[ prop ];
              }
              return value;
            }
```

```css
/* force scrollbar */
html { overflow-y: scroll; }

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* ---- isotope ---- */

.grid {
    padding-bottom:60px;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 20%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
      width: 50%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
      width: 100%;
    }
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.image{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;

}

.image:after {
    clear:both;
}

.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
      -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
      transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;


}

.overlay .title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
      -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
      transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
    padding:0 24px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    position:relative;
}
.overlay:hover h3{
    color: rgba(254,194,0,1);
    
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 1s;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {color:rgba(254,194,0,1); left:0px; top:10px;}
    50%  {color:rgba(254,194,0,1); left:0px; top:0px;}
    100% {color:rgba(254,194,0,1); left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {color:rgba(254,194,0,1);left:0px; top:10px;}
    50%  {color:rgba(254,194,0,1); left:0px; top:0px;}
    100% {color:rgba(254,194,0,1);left:0px; top:0px;}
}
.overlay a{
    cursor: hand;
}

.overlay p {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
      -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
      transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
    position: relative;
    font-size:12px;
line-height:18px;
    font-weight:100;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0;
}
.overlay:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
}
.overlay:hover p{
    color: rgba(254,194,0,1);
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        animation-name: tipos;
        animation-duration: 2s;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes tipos {
    0%   {color:#333; left:0px; top:20px;}
    50%  {color:#fff; left:0px; top:0px;}
    100% {color:#fff; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes tipos {
    0%   {color:#333;left:0px; top:20px;}
    50%  {color:#fff; left:0px; top:0px;}
    100% {color:#fff;left:0px; top:0px;}
}



.project-title{
    display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
}
.wrapper{
        position: absolute;
        display: table;
        z-index: 100;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /* text-align: center; */
        line-height: 24px;

}


.button-group{
    color:#FEC200;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align:center;
}
.button-group .button{
    background:transparent;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    font-size:0.8em;
    font-weight:300;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.button:hover{
    cursor:hand;
    border: solid 1px #FEC200 !important;
    color:#FEC200;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px !important;
    font-weight:300;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.button-group .button:focus{
    outline:0;
}


.is-checked {
    cursor:hand;
    border: solid 1px #FEC200 !important;
    color:#FEC200;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px !important;
    font-weight:300;
}
.fotoproy img{
    max-width:100%;
}
.fotoproy{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
.proyecto-imagen img{
border: 0px;
border-style: solid;
-webkit-transform-origin: left top;
-ms-transform-origin: left top;
-o-transform-origin: left top;
transform-origin: left top;
max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div style="padding:0 0 70px; margin:0;">

                <div id="filters" class="button-group">
                    <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">Todo</button>
                    <button class="button" data-filter=".branding">Identidad</button>
                    <button class="button" data-filter=".grafica">Gráfica</button>
                    <button class="button" data-filter=".website">Web</button>
                    <button class="button" data-filter=".video">Video</button>


                </div>
            </div>
      
      <div class="grid" style="position: relative; height: 727.205px;">
              <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

      <div class="grid-item website grafica" style="position: absolute; left: 79.9982%; top: 0px;"><img src="http://www.mi5studio.com/imgs/thumbs/appole.jpg" class="image" alt="Ole Resultados APP"><a class="overlay" href="proyecto.php?id=21"><div class="wrapper"><div class="project-title"><h3 class="title">Amistosos Internacionales</h3><div class="description"><p class="tipo">VER PROYECTO</p></div></div></div></a></div>

      <div class="grid-item website grafica" style="position: absolute; left: 79.9982%; top: 0px;"><img src="http://www.mi5studio.com/imgs/thumbs/ramosrevista.jpg" class="image" alt="Ole Resultados APP"><a class="overlay" href="proyecto.php?id=21"><div class="wrapper"><div class="project-title"><h3 class="title">Amistosos Internacionales</h3><div class="description"><p class="tipo">VER PROYECTO</p></div></div></div></a></div>
      <div class="grid-item website grafica" style="position: absolute; left: 79.9982%; top: 0px;"><img src="http://www.mi5studio.com/imgs/thumbs/camaratres.jpg" class="image" alt="Ole Resultados APP"><a class="overlay" href="proyecto.php?id=21"><div class="wrapper"><div class="project-title"><h3 class="title">Amistosos Internacionales</h3><div class="description"><p class="tipo">VER PROYECTO</p></div></div></div></a></div>

      <div class="grid-item website grafica" style="position: absolute; left: 79.9982%; top: 0px;"><img src="http://www.mi5studio.com/imgs/thumbs/lions.jpg" class="image" alt="Ole Resultados APP"><a class="overlay" href="proyecto.php?id=21"><div class="wrapper"><div class="project-title"><h3 class="title">Amistosos Internacionales</h3><div class="description"><p class="tipo">VER PROYECTO</p></div></div></div></a></div>
      
      
      
      </div>
```

Comment: When I test in the smartphone it works ok but the problem is in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I see a few issues:

Your loading 2 different versions of jQuery, version 2.1.1, just after the body tag of your page and a second, 3.2.1 at the end of your page.

Top of the page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>   
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
```

Likewise, you're loading imagesloaded and isotope.js after the body tag of the page  and then you are also loading masonry.js and a second, older version imagesloaded.js inside your plugins.js file at the end.

end of your page:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

You should remove your references to masonry and the older imagesloaded inside your plugins.js and re-arrange your javascript loading with only one jQuery script (3.2.1). I'm guessing that the 2 versions of jQuery and imagesloaded and having both masonry and isotope loading may be an issue?